# How do I put an image into my picturebox using ImageLocation?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have created a picturebox within my panel and I would like to fill it up with an image locally.

this is what I have done so far and the following code is just a small part of my panel creation code.

```
PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "pictureBox",
            Size = new Size(100, 50),
            Location = new Point(14, 17)
        };
        p.Controls.Add(picture);
        picture.ImageLocation = @"..\Image\1.jpg";
```

It does works but not fully as after I have launch my c# windows form application, it jus show a small white box with a red cross in the middle instead of the image. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting the image using `picture.ImageLocation()` works fine, but you are using a relative path.  Check your path against the location of the `.exe` after it is built.

For example, if your `.exe` is located at:

`<project folder>/bin/Debug/app.exe`

The image would have to be at:

`<project folder>/bin/Image/1.jpg`

---

Of course, you could just set the image at design-time (the `Image` property on the `PictureBox` property sheet).

If you must set it at run-time, one way to make sure you know the location of the image is to add the image file to your project.  For example, add a new folder to your project, name it `Image`.  Right-click the folder, choose "Add existing item" and browse to your image (be sure the file filter is set to show image files).  After adding the image, in the property sheet set the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.

At this point the image file will be copied when you build the application and you can use

```
picture.ImageLocation = @"Image\1.jpg";
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. how do i check the path against the location of the .exe?

Comment: It's a relative path... so wherever your executable is located, look up 1 folder, then from there look in the `Image` folder.

Comment: oh. okay fixed that issue. it is now able to load the "picture" however after the application load it jus came up with a white box instead of the image. any idea how to fix this? or does this have to do with the image size and my picturebox size?

Comment: @Thomas, no - shouldn't have anything to do with image or picture box size.  Unless the image is much larger and has a white background?  Then the picture box might only show the upper left corner, which would be white.

Comment: @Thomas - you can use `SizeMode` (try `Zoom`) to make sure the image is sized to fit the `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 4):

if you provide a bad path or a broken link, if the compiler cannot find the image, the picture box would display an X icon on its body.

```
PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "pictureBox",
            Size = new Size(100, 50),
            Location = new Point(14, 17),
            Image = Image.FromFile(@"c:\Images\test.jpg"),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        };
p.Controls.Add(picture);
```

OR

```
PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "pictureBox",
            Size = new Size(100, 50),
            Location = new Point(14, 17),
            ImageLocation = @"c:\Images\test.jpg",
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        };
p.Controls.Add(picture);
```

i'm not sure where you put images in your folder structure but you can find the path as bellow

```
 picture.ImageLocation = Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Resources\Images\1.jpg");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. it now displays a white box instead. is it because of my image size? because the original image and my picture box image size does not match.

Comment: @Thomas have you try using full path?

Comment: yes I have tried using the full path. it shows up a white box instead. normally i would have shown nothing. and if there is no image found, there would be a red cross. but now I think it is able to find the image file but it just shows a white box.

Comment: try setting  SizeMode as PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage