# Issue with path when trying to reference project media folder

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to reference images stored in a project folder

File path is SolutionName/ProjectName/Media/someImage.png

Properties of the images in the folder are
[image: Properties]

If I hardcode a test it works like:

```
var imageName = "C:/Test/TestImage/file.png";
```

But if I try something like:

```
var imageName = @"/ProjectName;component/Media/someImage.png"
```

it does not work!  How can I reference the folder in the project in C# WPF application VS2012? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN on Pack Uri's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Programming_with_Pack_URIs), when you are trying to reference a resource in code, you either need to fully qualify the `Uri`:

```
var imageName = new Uri("application://,,,/ProjectName;component/Media/someImage.png");
```

or you need to specify a relative `Uri`:

```
var imageName = new Uri("/ProjectName;component/Media/someImage.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have image folder like this:

ProjectName/bin/Images/yourImage.jpg

then you can use image like this:

```
picture.ImageLocation = @"Images\yourImage.jpg";
```

and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017978/how-do-i-put-an-image-into-my-picturebox-using-imagelocation)

or you can make easier by using :

```
Properties.Resources.ImageName
```

if you imported image into resources folder inside you project