# How to Load Image to PictureBox; based on the image Location stored in the DataBase

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, picturebox

I have sql database where I have image as saved image location

**eg:**

```
D:\Local Pictures\Users\XXXX_XXXX_1.jpg
```

I am trying to place it in the picture box using this code

```
DataConnection myCon = new DataConnection(); // Contains Data Connection String
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLS2012;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
con1.Open();
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From USER_TABLE WHERE USERID =" + userIdTextBox.Text,con1);

myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    nameTextBox.Text = (myReader["FIRST_NAME"].ToString());
    lnameTextBox.Text = (myReader["LAST_NAME"].ToString());
    posTextBox.Text = (myReader["POSITION"].ToString());
    emailTextBox.Text = (myReader["E_MAIL"].ToString());
    phoneTextBox.Text = (myReader["PHONE"].ToString());
    usernameTextBox.Text = (myReader["USERNAME"].ToString());
    userLevelTextBox.Text = (myReader["USER_LEVEL"].ToString());
    string filename = (myReader["PROFILE_PICTURE"].ToString());
    profilePicBox.ImageLocation = filename;

}
```

When I execute this code I am getting small x picture white background in image. How to fix and load the image

Comment: Are you hosting Winforms' PictureBox in WPF window? Or are you using it in WinForms? And what exactly happens with image - is it loaded and incorrectly represented or does it fail to load at all?

Comment: @EugenePodskal this image i am getting http://i.imgur.com/rMf8qAb.png

Comment: @EugenePodskal i am using it on winforms application

Comment: @  Alston Antony : have you got other values through this query? is their any error showing while execution?

Comment: @SujithKarivelil yep all the queries are working perfectly on the picturebox shows the error image i not even getting any exception

Comment: @EugenePodskal i didn't get you mate

Comment: @ Alston Antony : See my updates in the answer hope that it will help you to recover from this problem

Comment: When reading image location from a database table I suggest to store only a relative path where the image can be found. The missing part of the path should come from a configuration file that can be easily changed if the need arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Loading:**

MSDN isn't exactly clear on this matter - [ImageLocation property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation(v=vs.110).aspx), but it seems that setting the `ImageLocation` property may not exactly load the image, so you may try to use [PictureBox.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead:

```
...
string filename = (myReader["PROFILE_PICTURE"].ToString());
profilePicBox.Load(filename);
```

**EDIT**

`ImageLocation` should probably work fine, just make sure that your paths are correct and you do not use relative paths - [How do I put an image into my picturebox using ImageLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017978/how-do-i-put-an-image-into-my-picturebox-using-imagelocation)

**Positioning and size:**

And make sure that your [PictureBox properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) related to size and position can handle different image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

make this change in your while loop

```
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            nameTextBox.Text = (myReader["FIRST_NAME"].ToString());
            lnameTextBox.Text = (myReader["LAST_NAME"].ToString());
            posTextBox.Text = (myReader["POSITION"].ToString());
            emailTextBox.Text = (myReader["E_MAIL"].ToString());
            phoneTextBox.Text = (myReader["PHONE"].ToString());
            usernameTextBox.Text = (myReader["USERNAME"].ToString());
            userLevelTextBox.Text = (myReader["USER_LEVEL"].ToString());
            string filename = (myReader["PROFILE_PICTURE"].ToString());
            profilePicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(filename )

        }
```